# Error mapped Hibernate @NamedQuery

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

Hi all I have Hibernate class like below:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "getUser", query = "from tuser u where u.username =:username and u.passwordHash = :password"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "getUserId", query = "select u.id from tuser u where u.username =:username"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "getAllUsers", query = "from tuser u where u.state='1'"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "loadUser", query = "from tuser u where u.username =:username"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "changeState",query="update tuser u SET u.state='0' where u.id=:id")
        })
@Entity
@Table(name = "tuser", catalog = "apw", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") })
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
}
```

1. POJO name: User
 2. Oracle table: tuser (because I have error if give name "user" as table name)

Here's for the Service:

```
public interface UserService extends GenericService<User> {
    public void deleteUser(int id);
    public User loadUser(String username);
    public List<User> getAllUsers();
    User getUser(String username,String password);
}
```

When I run the program show error like below:

```
2018-04-26 11:30:14,610 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000177: Error in named query: loadTuser
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tuser is not mapped [from tuser u where u.username =:username]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tuser is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
```

<<< Same also for getAllUsers, deleteUser, getUser >>>

**Finally, my question is How to map @NamedQuery to tuser Oracle table?**

Thanks you and I'm sorry for bad English.

Comment: change your queries to use "User" instead of tuser as your entity name is User  NOT tuser.

Comment: Oh I never thought like that, Thanks you

Comment: Happy to help :)